# socat and gawk piped

Tags: pipe, gawk, socat

I'm trying to manipulate a TCP stream using gawk. The TCP server streams out a text string separated by whitespaces.
I want to add an extra string at the beginning and then separate the remaining fields with commas instead of whitespaces.
I've tried as below:

```
socat TCP4:127.0.0.1:8888 - | gawk '{out=""; for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){if (i > 1) {out=out","$i} else out="Hello,"$i}; print out}'
```

which is working. But now I want to redirect that flow outside on a second socket like below:

```
socat TCP4:127.0.0.1:5754 PIPE gawk '{out=""; for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){if (i > 1) {out=out","$i} else out="$LZER0,POS,"$i}; print out}' | socat - TCP:127.0.0.1:9999
```

But nothing at 127.0.0.1:9999 I've tried to listen with:

socat tcp-listen:9999,reuseaddr,ignoreeof,fork stdout

but nothing.

I've made another test:

```
socat TCP4:127.0.0.1:5754 PIPE gawk '{out=""; for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){if (i > 1) {out=out","$i} else out="$LZER0,POS,"$i}; print out}' | socat - -
```

but again nothing on my stdout.

Can you help me?

Answer (score 0):

It is likely that the output of `gawk` is buffered when its output goes to a pipe and that there's not enough output generated to flush the buffer.

To flush the output buffer manually, use `fflush()` in the `gawk` program:

```
gawk '{ ... ; print out; fflush() }'
```